# Clicking on an image not working as intended

Tags: javascript, html, function, event-listener

I made a game where you need to click the image on the left side of the screen that you do not see on the opposite side to get to the next level. For some reason, when you click any image on the left side you still go to the next level. When you click the wrong image it should say game over. Right now it only does that when the whitespace is clicked. Any tips?

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Matching Game</title>
    <style>
      img {
        position: absolute;
     }  
     div {
       position: absolute;
       width: 500px;
       height: 500px;
     }
     #rightSide {
       left: 500px;
       border-left: 1px solid;
     }
   </style>
</head>
<body onload="generateFaces()">
<h1>Matching Game</h1>
<p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left.</p>

<div id="leftSide"></div>
<div id="rightSide"></div>

<script >
    let numberOfFaces = 5;
    const theLeftSide = document.querySelector("#leftSide");
    const theRightSide = document.querySelector("#rightSide");

    function generateFaces() {
        for (let i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
            let face = document.createElement("img");
            face.src = 'images/smile.png';

            const randomTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + 1;
            const randomLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + 1;

            face.style.top = randomTop + 'px';
            face.style.left = randomLeft + 'px';

            theLeftSide.appendChild(face);

            theLeftSide.lastChild.addEventListener('click', nextLevel);
            document.body.addEventListener('click', gameOver);
        }   

        const leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
        leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
        theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages); 
        
    function nextLevel(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        numberOfFaces += 5;

        while (theLeftSide.firstChild) {
            theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstChild);
        }

        while (theRightSide.firstChild) {
            theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstChild);
        }
        
        generateFaces();
    }

    function gameOver() {
        alert('Game Over!');
        document.body.removeEventListener('click', gameOver);
        theLeftSide.lastChild.removeEventListener('click', nextLevel);
    }
    
    } 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code that I have shown in the body is the entire code and it works when I use it so I am not sure what you mean by runnable. I will edit the question and add screenshots to clarify.

Comment: Sorry I tried to reword my question and I have provided a screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

notice

```js
for (let i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
    let face = document.createElement("img");
    ...
    theLeftSide.appendChild(face);

    // you do this in every loop
    theLeftSide.lastChild.addEventListener('click', nextLevel);
}
```

put the `theLeftSide.lastChild.addEventListener('click', nextLevel);` outside loop for it to work

Comment: because when you do `addEventListener` the event will always be there until you call `removeEventListener` so every loop you add an image and the last child (the image you just added) is given the event but never removes it which is why when you click any of them it calls `nextLevel()`